# Change pdf's to stop downloading files

Tags: pdf-reader

This used to be my workflow: Click on pdf -> automatically open pdf in tab

Now that firefox (and other browsers) have stopped in browser use of adobe reader (and adobe reader 11 or whatever it is has tabs) my workflow is this:

Click on pdf -> Browser downloads pdf -> Find and Open pdf in downloads list -> Switch to adobe reader and read pdf

I would like something a little more automatic, like the first way.

How can I have a better workflow and shorten the process for viewing pdfs?

Note: I open hundreds of pdfs a week, and I print some of them, so I'm not going to use an in browser pdf viewer. The printing, viewing and searching capabilities are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox options you can set it to automagically launch an application to view pdfs by going to Options -> Applications -> Type "pdf" and then changing the application that opens pdfs.

Where I have "Preview in Firefox" below, you should be able to select the program you want to run.

[image]